# Remove duplicate rows from Html Table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to remove  of table if all  values of that table are same 
i am using below table
You can view this in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spdc9oyv/6/) 
    
        
            MY Name00:566£88.877
        

            My Name00:566£88.87167

```
        <tr class="Awaitingdispatch" align="center" valign="middle">
        <td>XYZ </td><td>02.52</td><td>6</td><td>£150.25</td><td class="hideGridColumn">167</td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="Awaitingdispatch" align="center" valign="middle">
        <td>My Name</td><td>02:56</td><td>167</td><td>£150.25</td><td class="hideGridColumn">167</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css: 
     .gridview-container table 
        {
            font-size:12px;
            }

```
    .gridview-container tr:first-child td
    {
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        }
    .hideGridColumn
    {
        display:none;
    }

    .dispatch 
    {background : lightgreen;
        }
.PRESS 
    {background :#FF9933;
        }
        .Awaitingdispatch
         {background :yellow;
        }
```

[DEMO On JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spdc9oyv/6/)

Here i want to remove row if all cells are equal
Note : i want ignore hidden cells

Comment: You forgot to include `jquery` library in jsfiddle.. I have updated it.. http://jsfiddle.net/spdc9oyv/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below deletes all rows with similar values:

```
function removeDuplicateRows($table){
    function getVisibleRowText($row){
        return $row.find('td:visible').text().toLowerCase();
    }

    $table.find('tr').each(function(index, row){
        var $row = $(row);
        $row.nextAll('tr').each(function(index, next){
            var $next = $(next);
            if(getVisibleRowText($next) == getVisibleRowText($row))
                $next.remove();
        })
    });
}

removeDuplicateRows($('table'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wke3Laej/)